# Trying to parallelize the outer loop of this matrix-matrix multiplication using OpenMP

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to add pragma statement(s) to the code as well.

```
//Calculating the product of the matrix
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
   mat_ans[i][j] = 0;
   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      mat_ans[i][j] += (mat_1[i][k] * mat_2[k][j]);
   }
   }
}
```

I am trying to make my code as efficient as possible and I've been doing research on how to do this. OpenMP seems like a good option. But I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty new to c++11 and am just trying to learn as fast as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
//Calculating the product of the matrix
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      mat_ans[i][j] = 0;
      #pragma omp simd
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
          mat_ans[i][j] += (mat_1[i][k] * mat_2[k][j]);
      }
   }
}
```

If you are unsure about how to use openMP watch this [Introduction to openMp playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nE-xN4Bf8XI&list=PLLX-Q6B8xqZ8n8bwjGdzBJ25X2utwnoEG) although it is a playlist from 2013 most of it is still relevant, it teaches you how to use most of the core features in openMP.

To me your code doesn't look efficient.
In code where you are accessing and using elements of arrays/ vectors you should try and be aware of how many times you access certain elements and how that can affect performance, many algorithms are limited by memory bandwidth. There is a wikipedia article on [loop nest optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_nest_optimization), that explains various optimisations that you can make on a nested loops based matrix multiplication.

Once you get that working try and take a look at a [cache-oblivious algorithm for matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Divide_and_conquer_algorithm), this algorithm does not need specifics about the cache without wasting memory bandwidth.

Finally watch out for integer overflow, if n >= 65537 your code might break.